# Where can I see the Forms folder of a document library?

Tags: form, document-template

If I open the link http://sharePointserver/nameofdoclibrary/Forms in my browser the library is empty. As I read there should be the document templates and the New Item etc forms in it.

When I open the SharePoint 2013 Designer I see the three default forms in the Forms folder but no document template, even if I uploaded one and use it already.

I want to delete old document templates and view them. Anyone with an idea?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

You can also open SharePoint Designer -- > All files --> Document library -- > Forms --> Templatename.dotx

If template is attached to any content type, inside Forms there will be a folder with Content type name and template will be present inside it.

Comment: I am not using content types and as I said in the question when I open the library in SharePoint designer and click on Forms there are the three forms (newitems, edit, display) but no doc templates

Comment: Did you open the library through  All files option on the left hand side?

Comment: I opened it through the navigation on the left hand side (Side Objects). I don't see an 'All files' heading. Do you use SharePoint Designer 2013?

Comment: Do you have an idea why I cannot see the templace doc in SharePoint designer?

Answer (score 4):

Document templates are not visible in Forms folder but they are visible in Mapped network drive.

So follow below links to map your library in network drive.

http://mroffice365.com/2012/02/using-sharepoint-document-library-as-a-network-drive/

https://hubone.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/200167580-SharePoint-Using-Explorer-View-or-Mapped-Network-Drives

Comment: Do you think there is no other way? I think its weird that you cannot delete old templates out of the folder without mapping them. Maybe with sharepoint designer or somehow?

Comment: you can do that using SP designer. try what **Unnie** said

Comment: This doesn't work. Maybe you know why I cant see the docs in SharePoint Designer (see my comments under Unnies post)?.. :/

Comment: you should see all file in SP designer. Clear your SP designer cache and try again.

Comment: I tried that already. " when I open the library in SharePoint designer and click on Forms there are the three forms (newitems, edit, display) but no doc templates" --> can you see your templates if you do the same thing?

Comment: Because Unnie wrote I should open it through 'All files' which I don't see.